# Using SpectorJs with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to use `spector.js` npm package with cypress to test WebGL. When i run the test it gives an error `'e is null'`
[image]

I am trying to capture the JSON using `spector.js` inside the cypress.

```
var spector = new SPECTOR.Spector();
            
spector.onCapture.add((capture) => {
            // Do something with capture.
            var myEvent = new CustomEvent("SpectorOnCaptureEvent", { detail: { captureString: JSON.stringify(capture) } });
            document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
});
        
var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
spector.captureCanvas(canvas);
```